# Ubuntu - Recommended Minimum System Requirements

Tags: laptop, support

Can I install and run Ubuntu on this machine?

> - AMD Dual-Core E1-6015 APU with
> - Radeon R2 Graphics (1.4 GHz, 1 MB cache)
> - 4 GB DDR3L-1600 SDRAM (1 x 4 GB)

If yes, which version of Ubuntu should I run?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can run any version you want. I use the Unity version of Ubuntu on two old machines, that comparable or slower than yours. You can try and if it's too slow or laggy for you, you may try Lubuntu or Xubuntu. Xubuntu runs very fine on an very very old Single-Core machine of my mother, which has less than 1 GB of memory.

Answer (score 0):

[According to specification](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements) minim requirements are:

```
> 700 MHz processor (about Intel Celeron or better) 
> 512 MiB RAM (system memory)
> 5 GB of hard-drive space (or USB stick, memory card or external drive but see LiveCD for an alternative approach) 
> VGA capable of 1024x768 screen resolution
> Either a CD/DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media Internet access is helpful
```

Your machine exceeds these requirements, so yes you can.

Answer (score 0):

My laptop is :

AMD A4-3305 with GPU &
4GB RAM

and it is smooth to running ubuntu in any version.

you should try, all running perfect and nothing to worry.
if something terrible happen, just ask.